# UI Path Studio - Data Scraping - Cannot find pattern

Tags: palantir-foundry, uipath-studio

This website (Palantir Foundry - which is a pay-only cloud service, so it is not publicly available) Seems to use some React Tables package that creates a table with headers (that one can sort, filter, etc) and then rows of data.

We want to capture the header row and the first data row with UIPath Studio (Enterprise) 2020.10.2

When I can use the Chrome extension to grab a row, but when go for the second element in the pattern i get the pop-up error “Cannot find all pattern elements”. Any suggestions on things to try?

Pictures below might help:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should check Blueprint.js https://blueprintjs.com/ which is the open source react library used to build those UIs, maybe it helps :crossed_fingers:

Comment: Care to explain your overall setup here, and why you'd want to scrape that information? Perhaps Foundry has an API you can use to fetch this info?

Comment: as other mentioned, can you explain what you want to achieve ? as there are easier ways to get schema and data